# Promise in the template engine does not seem to work

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set a $scope variable to a promise and use that scope variable in the template engine but it does not seem to work.

In controller:

```
  $scope.getUser = function() {
    // I am returning a promise
    // need this to be in a function so angular calls the function
    // more than once as the promise may change if a new user logs in,
    // i.e. myself is now someone new
    return UserService.getMyself();
  }
```

Service:

```
  var userDeferred = $q.defer();

  // Some other code here which resolves the promise.
  // I have verified that the promise does get resolved.      

  service.getMyself = function () {
    return userDeferred.promise;
  };
```

In html:

```
 <button>
  {{getUser().username}} 
 </button>
```

I read this from the angular docs:

> $q promises are recognized by the templating engine in angular, which
>   means that in templates you can treat promises attached to a scope as
>   if they were the resulting values.

But I imagine I misinterpreted that and I am using this wrong.  I have function return because the user could change (promise changes) and I want my template engine to pick up the fact the something has changed with regards to the promise (ie I created a new promise as the user changed and I want my template to see that.

Edit:

Here is a plunker that show what I am trying to get at:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6J9pWY?p=preview

Comment: Maybe that's one function too much, can you try `$scope.getUser = UserService.getMyself`?

Comment: Yeah that did not work either, good idea though!

Comment: also $scope.user = UserService.getMyself() did not seem to work with {{user.username}} either.

Comment: Show what is there in UserService.getMySelf()

Comment: Updated question with UserService.getMyself() method

Comment: You know that a promise only gets resolved once, right?

Comment: Yup, only once.  But on my signin page I create a new promise as a new user is signing in.  That way if controllers ask my service for the user again they will wait on a brand new deferred.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is not working for you (you do not give enough information) but here is a sample code that seems to work:

http://embed.plnkr.co/Ve5KV8m1UbVHeAtpTjFK/preview

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .factory('UserService', function($q, $timeout) {

    var getMyself = function() {
      var userDeferred = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function() {
        userDeferred.resolve({username: 'root'});
      }, 2000);

      return userDeferred.promise;
    };

    return {
      getMyself: getMyself
    };
  })

  .controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope, UserService) {
      $scope.user = UserService.getMyself();
  });
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
    <h1>User:</h1>
    {{user.username}}
  </body>
```

Comment: Sure that works but I want the user returned in a function from the controller so that angular reevalutes it more than once.  I.E. what if my user logs out and new user logs in.  In that case you $scope.user = UserService.getMyself() has already been evaluated and will never change.  I put a comment in the UserController to hopefully clarify.

Comment: when you do that, it keeps calling the function again and again. I do not know why. Perhaps has something to do with watchers. Insert a `console.log` statement into the function and you will see.